# How to set ApexCharts height on page load then render chart on scroll into view

Tags: apexcharts

I have got a project with some ApexCharts and they're working perfectly, but I was wondering how I can render the charts enough to just set the height on page load then animate in the chart when it's scrolled into view.

```
var graphs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-graph]')

for(var i = 0; i < graphs.length; i++) {
    if (isScrolledIntoView(graphs[i])) {

        if (!graphs[i].classList.contains('has-animated')) {
            graphs[i].classList.add('has-animated')

            var data = JSON.parse(graphs[i].dataset.graph)

            var chart = new ApexCharts(graphs[i], data)

            chart.render()
        }
    }
}
```

- `isScrolledIntoView` is a function checking if each item is in view or not.
- Setting the `is-animated` class to only reveal each graph only once.
- The content in the graph is being set in a CMS so the data is being stored in a `data-graph` attribute on the graph div.